# Ionic 4 side menu not closing in samsung browser

Tags: ionic-framework, menu, ionic4

I have `ionic side menu` that closes fine on **clicking** `ion-item` in **chrome browser**. But it doesn't show the same `behaviour` in **samsung browser**. It doesn't close once opened. I tried to close using code also. But it's not closing. I **wrapped** the `ion-item` in `ion-menu-toggle` like this

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-menu-toggle>
   <ion-item lines="none" routerLink="/home">
    <ion-icon name="business" color="secondary" slot="start"></ion-icon>
    <ion-label>Business</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-menu-toggle>
</ion-list>
```

someone explain me the issue and help me out

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code maybe it is work's for you

```
<ion-menu-toggle menu="first" autoHide="false">
```

Comment: I tried it but it's also not working. Actually I have separate component for menu and wrapped it inside ion-menu. <ion-app>
  <ion-menu side="start" menuId="mainMenu">
      <app-my-menu></app-my-menu>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app> like this.  will that be a issue?

Comment: can you share whole code then i can reproduce this issue.